# ModuleName-Swift.h file not found inside of CocoaPod Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

### Issue

I have a CocoaPod project created using `pod lib create`. There are some Objective-C classes that can be used inside the example project — I am now trying to add a NSObject subclass written in Swift.

The Swift class was created and the bridging header was added to the classes directory.

I try to import the Swift bridging header into the .m file of another class inside the pod project:

`#import "PROFlyoutViewController-Swift.h"`

When I compile I get `'ModuleName-Swift.h' file not found`

When the import statement is:

`#import <ModuleName/ModuleName-Swift.h>`
or

`#import "ModuleName/ModuleName-Swift.h"`

it compiles and is usable!

### But...

I return to the file, indexing runs (I assume) and all of a sudden I get:

`ModuleName/ModuleName-Swift.h file not found`.

Autocomplete is broken on that file and any use of that class shows a warning.

### Question

When using trying to use a Swift Bridging header within the files of a pod project, how should it be imported? What do I need to do in order to get autocomplete working and compilable?

Comment: Did u get this resolved. I am on a very similar situation.

Comment: Me too. Any success?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@import PROFlyoutViewController;` instead as it is an external module.

Answer (score -2):

See the below Example of my TableDemo project

[image]

**To import Swift code into Objective-C from the same target**

Import the Swift code from that target into any Objective-C .m file within that target using this syntax and substituting the appropriate name:

```
#import "TableDemo-Swift.h"
```

The Swift files in your target will be visible in Objective-C .m files containing this import statement. For information on using Swift from Objective-C code, see Using Swift from Objective-C.